# inline-block not working with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

Always problems with IE8 ...

I'm trying to use inline-block to align some text with the top right edge of an image. It works fine in FF, but of course, doesn't work in IE8.

Here's a Fiddle for what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/9DPv5/

I've tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Did nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Did nothing.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    li { display: inline !imporant; }
</style>   
<![endif]-->
```

Didn't fix the problem and broke stylings elsewhere on the page.

```
margin-right:1px
```

The block already has a margin set on it, so this ofc didn't change anything.

Not really sure what else to try. I don't think anything in the CSS doesn't work with IE8.

I found these too, but not sure where to put them to test:

```
.divInlineBlock
{
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}
```

and

```
display: inline-table;
```

**Edit:** It seems that the image is aligning correctly, it's just the text that isn't.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Oh I see. I am removing my answer (adding `display: inline; zoom: 1;`) because it doesnt seem to be of much help :(. Posting this comment just to let others know that we did try that option also. I will update if I find any other better answers.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why none of the solutions are working. If only my place of work used a real browser I wouldn't have any problems at all!

Comment: did you replace the inline-block with those two lines (or) did you just append them below? do you have a separate stylesheet for IE8 and below? If yes, can you try removing the `display:inline-block` and include the replacement i suggested?

Comment: I appended them below first, then tried replacing them. No seperate stylesheet for IE8.

Comment: Oh :( If replace also doesn't seem to work, then I am out of answers. Every other solution I am getting you seem to have tried already.

Comment: I've found the solution, thanks for helping me look though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of faffing around (I have to log out of the website to test, then log back in EVERY time I make a change, to see if it works...don't ask :( ) I've finally fixed it.

I changed:

```
#accordion .foobar .foo {
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    height:125px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
```

to:

```
#accordion .foobar .foo {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    height:125px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
```

Adding the "float:left;" to the image fixed this problem.